# Set width to the default in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am importing a dropdown picker in React Native from react-native-select-dropdown.  When looking through the source code I noticed that the width is already set to 50% but I would like the width to grow with the text inside of it.  How do I set the width to the default so that it is no longer hardcoded?  I have tried 'default', 'invert', and 'unset' already but all 3 throw an error.

Here is an example of my code so far:

```
<SelectDropdown
    defaultValue={Constants['walletList'][defaultDropdownValue().nickName]}
    data={Constants['walletList']}
    buttonStyle={{
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        paddingHorizontal: 0,
    }}
    buttonTextStyle={{
        fontSize: 14,
        padding: 0,
        margin: 0,
        marginHorizontal: 0,
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the width of a dropdown grow with the text inside of it, you will probably need to set the width property of the dropdown to "auto" instead of a specific value.

Comment: When I set the width to 'auto' it looks like it gives it no width.  Nothing shows up.